# Alternate letters in upper case

Tags: c++, c, string

As the below code should convert the given String into alternative upper or lower case. A str‌ing S (only alphabets) is passed as input.

The printed output should contain alphabets in odd positions in each word in uppercase and alphabets in even positions in each word in lowercase.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main()
{
    char str[100];
    int i;
    scanf("%s",str);
    for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++){
        if((i%2)==1)
            str[i]=tolower(str[i]);
        else
            str[i]=toupper(str[i]);
    }
    printf("%s",str);
    return 0;
}
```

The input will be `tREE GiVES us fruiTS`  and the expected output should be `TrEe GiVeS Us FrUiTs`  BUT what im getting is just first string **TrEe** What should i do to get full string

Comment: Is this a C++ question or a C question? This all looks like C code, which means that the C++ tag is unnecessary.

Comment: %s reads only one word. Use getline.

Comment: even thou c++ user may also answer this question. So what i place that tag

Comment: A C++ user will have access to features that  C programmer will not.  If you're doing it in C, then a C++ answer may not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf("%s, str)` reads in a string until the first whitespace character. So when you type "tree gives us fruits" it reads in "tree" and then see's the whitespace and stops.

Try using `fgets(str, 100, stdin)` instead

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/